# How to mock JWT token to use it with Mockito and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, mockito

I have a controller which gives the user a 403 response unless they are authenticated with a JWT token which is passed as a Bearer token via the authorization header.
I'm looking for resources on how to test this with Mockito but I'm not very successful so far as most of them tell me to use the @WithMockUser annotation, which I understand is for Spring security yes, but does not include the mocking for a JWT token. I've tried to mock a few objects such as the UserDetailsClass and the JwtFilter and even hardcoding the bearer token but I think there should be more to it.

```
@MockBean
private CategoryCommandService categoryCommandService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

@MockBean
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@MockBean
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter filter;


@Test
void testCreateCategory() throws Exception {

    CategoryCreateDto categoryCreateDto = new CategoryCreateDto("category");
    CategoryCreateDto categoryCreateResponseDto = new CategoryCreateDto(UUID.fromString("2da4002a-31c5-4cc7-9b92-cbf0db998c41"), "category");

    String jsonCreate = asJsonString(categoryCreateDto);
    String jsonResponse = asJsonString(categoryCreateResponseDto);

    RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/api/adverts/category")
            .content(jsonCreate)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmb29AZW1haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjM4ODU1MzA1LCJpYXQiOjE2Mzg4MTkzMDV9.q4FWV7yVDAs_DREiF524VZ-udnqwV81GEOgdCj6QQAs")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    mockMvc.perform(request).andReturn();

    when(categoryCommandService.createCategory(categoryCreateDto)).thenReturn(
            categoryCreateResponseDto);

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(content().json(jsonResponse, true))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value("2da4002a-31c5-4cc7-9b92-cbf0db998c41"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title").value("category"))
            .andReturn();

    logger.info(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
}
```

Here my controller:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/adverts/category")
@RestController
public class CategoryCommandController {

@Autowired
private CategoryCommandService categoryCommandService;

@Autowired
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> createCategory(@RequestBody CategoryCreateDto categoryCreateDto) {

    if (categoryCreateDto.getTitle() != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(categoryCommandService.createCategory(categoryCreateDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new FeedbackMessage("Missing title"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
}
```

And here my filter:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import static com.example.adverts.SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    if (path.equals(SIGN_UP_URL)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    String username = null;
    String jwt = null;

    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
    } else {

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
    }

    if (username != null) {

        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }


}

}
```

And JwtUtil class:

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {

private String SECRET_KEY = "secret";

public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
}

public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
}

public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}

private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
}

public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
}

private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

    return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
}

public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractUsername(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}
}
```

Here is the whole Github branch.

https://github.com/francislainy/adverts-backend/tree/dev_jwt

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

For clarity if I hardcode a valid token I get a 200 status code but my tests will still fail with nothing returned for content whereas before JWT and Spring security they were passing.

[image]

Comment: You have a utility function which can generate a JWT. Why not use it in the test to generate a fresh token and put it in the header? I would probably even generate the token once for all tests which use a valid token.

Comment: Even when I hardcode a valid token it won't work. It'll give me a 200 status code yes but the tests will fail with nothing to print for the result. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you create a branch that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: https://github.com/francislainy/adverts-backend/tree/dev_jwt

Comment: If writing unit-tests, just ignorea `Authorization` header. All that is need is `@MockBean JwtDecoder` and popolate test security context with the right type of `Authentication` instance. For `JwtAuthenticationToken`, there are at least three options list In my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is using

```
@MockBean
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
```

Which make JwtRequestFilter perform wrongly in

```java
    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
    }
```

As `username` will always return null from the mock bean.

To use the actual `JwtUtils`
Add `includeFilters` to include it in spring context,
then we also need to mock `myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` used in `JwtRequestFilter`. After that the test will pass.
Refer to comment inside below code for the changes.

```java
@WebMvcTest(value = CategoryCommandController.class, includeFilters = {
        // to include JwtUtil in spring context
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = JwtUtil.class)})
class CategoryCommandControllerTest {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoryCommandController.class);

    @MockBean
    private CategoryCommandService categoryCommandService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter filter;

    //    @WithMockUser
    @Test
    void testCreateCategory() throws Exception {

        CategoryCreateDto categoryCreateDto = new CategoryCreateDto("category");
        CategoryCreateDto categoryCreateResponseDto = new CategoryCreateDto(UUID.fromString("2da4002a-31c5-4cc7-9b92-cbf0db998c41"), "category");

        String jsonCreate = asJsonString(categoryCreateDto);
        String jsonResponse = asJsonString(categoryCreateResponseDto);
        UserDetails dummy = new User("foo@email.com", "foo", new ArrayList<>());
        String jwtToken = jwtUtil.generateToken(dummy);
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/api/adverts/category")
                .content(jsonCreate)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
// Below line is not used
//        mockMvc.perform(request).andReturn();

        //             Should be createCategory(eq(categoryCreateDto))?
        when(categoryCommandService.createCategory(categoryCreateDto)).thenReturn(
                categoryCreateResponseDto);
        // Mock Service method used in JwtRequestFilter
        when(myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(eq("foo@email.com"))).thenReturn(dummy);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
//                .andExpect(content().json(jsonResponse, true))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value("2da4002a-31c5-4cc7-9b92-cbf0db998c41"))
//                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title").value("category"))
                .andReturn();

        logger.info(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time looking into this issue. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We just fixed the issue (accepting the other answer for being a more elegant solution).

**1st and easier option:**

Disable filter authentication for controller test classes:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class CategoryCommandControllerTest {
```

You can then perhaps test jwt authorization separately.

**2nd and perhaps better option:**

Remove the extra pieces from the configure method within the WebSecurity class to end up with only this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Then under the JwtRequestFilter class add a return when a 403 is caught on the else part of this if block.

```
 if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        return;
    }
```

And move the doChain.filter piece outside of the other if block.

```
  if (username != null) {

        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }

        // chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

Comment: Both answers work, however this one requires disabling security filters on the context of the tests, which we didn't want to do at that time.

Comment: And what about the answer below (`@MockBean JwtDecoder jwtDecoder` with either  `@WithMockJwtAuth` or `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()), did you try it? Cause it's way simpler.

Answer (score 1):

`@MockBean JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;` should be enough in association with either (in my own preference order):

- @WithMockJwtAuth from https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons
- mockMvc.perform(get(...).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()...)) I contributed to spring-security-test. IMO, less readable than annotation (see sample below) and also usable for `@Controller` unit tests only when annotation can be used without `MockMvc`
- a mock you put in security context with `SecurityContextHolder.getSecurityContext.setAuthentication(mockJwtAuth)`. This requires more coding and also more knowledge of `JwtAuthenticationToken` internals.

The first two in action:

```java
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
@Import(SampleApi.WebSecurityConfig.class)
class GreetingControllerAnnotatedTest {

    @MockBean JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL", claims = @OpenIdClaims(sub = "Ch4mpy", preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void greetWithAnnotation() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }

    @Test
    void greetWithPostProcessor() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()
                .authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL"))).jwt(jwt -> {
                    jwt.subject("Ch4mpy");
                    jwt.claims(claims -> claims.put(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME, "Tonton Pirate"));
                }))).andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }
}
```

Complete sample [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken)